# Send different checkbox names from HTML to PHP in one form

Tags: php, html, forms, checkbox

I'm relatively new to html and php. I'm trying to use values chosen in an html form in php.

I've found lots of examples, how to read out the html `form` values in php when there is only one `form name` like `vehicle[]`.
But I would like to differentiate between types of `input` (vehicle or accommodation) and still have only one `submit button`. I've tried the following example, but it doesn't work ...

The html snippet from test.html:

```
<form action="form.php" method="POST">
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle[]" value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle[]" value="Car" checked> I have a car<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="accomodation[]" value="House"> I have a house<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="accomodation[]" value="Yurt"> I have a yurt<br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The php snippet from form.php:

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
    if(!empty($_POST['vehicle'])) 
    {
      foreach($_POST['vehicle'] as $vehiclecheck)
      {
        echo $vehiclecheck;
        echo "<br>";
      } 
    }
    if(!empty($_POST['accomodation'])) 
    {
      foreach($_POST['accomodation'] as $accomodationcheck)
      {
        echo $accomodationcheck;
        echo "<br>";
      } 
    }

  }
?>
```

Is there a simple way to get what I want? Or do I need a workaround?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, what doesn't work?

Comment: Never name anything "submit" in a form. It will block JavaScript submission. Give the input a name and test it: `<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="subbut">` `if(isset($_POST['subbut']))`

Answer (score 2):

```
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">  //name attribute missing here
```

Comment: NEVER name anything "submit" in a form

Comment: @mplungjan why's that?

Comment: You will block submission by JavaScript and you will spend days figuring out why

Comment: @mplungjan And what if you don't submit by JavaScript?

Comment: You will one day. So get in the habit of never naming anything submit. Also never assign a click handler to a submit button, instead use the form submit handler

Comment: @mplungjan Dude, it might be valid, but the question isn't tagged with JS / jQuery.

Comment: Dude, does not matter. Just keep it in mind

Answer (score 2):

Try this one. For sake of simplicity, it's just one file *form.php*

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    if(!empty($_POST['vehicle'])) {
        foreach($_POST['vehicle'] as $vehiclecheck) {
            var_dump($vehiclecheck);
        } 
    }
    if (!empty($_POST['accomodation'])) {
        foreach($_POST['accomodation'] as $accomodationcheck) {
            var_dump($accomodationcheck);
        }
    }
}
?>
<form action="form.php" method="POST">
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle[]" value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle[]" value="Car" checked> I have a car<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="accomodation[]" value="House"> I have a house<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="accomodation[]" value="Yurt"> I have a yurt<br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Few notes:

1.) Try following coding style guides, for PHP it's PSR-2 http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/.

2.) In your example you tried to check whether post field called 'submit' is not empty. In fact, this field was not present and was always empty)

3.) Using var_dump is better way of simplistic debugging compared to echo, because it could be better set up, shows variable types, you don't need to write a new line explicitly etc.

4.) There's aslo a great source of how to get better in PHP, try it http://www.phptherightway.com/